# Are micro/ultra DVD drives (i.e. those without drawers) supported?

Tags: drivers, dvd, eject

I have a system with a Matsushita/Panasonic optical drive with no drawer i.e. it should detect when a disk is inserted and ingests it automatically.

During boot, I can sucessfully insert a disk, however, once Ubuntu is running, the drive no longer detects and ingests a disk.

Nevertheless, the drive is working as any disk inserted during boot can be played, etc.

I am new to Linux so struggling a bit to find relevant diagnostics information.

If a disk is inserted during boot, I can eject it with the command `eject`; however, inspite of a sucessfull ejection I get an error:

```
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

If I insert a disk to the point where it would normally be ingested and use the command `eject -t`, the disk is not ingested and I have an error:

```
eject: CD-ROM tray close command failed: Input/output error
```

`lshw` shows the drive as correctly identified:

```
*-cdrom

          description: DVD-RAM writer
          product: DVD-RAM UJ-875S
          vendor: MATSHITA
          physical id: 0.1.0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          logical name: /dev/cdrw
          logical name: /dev/dvd
          logical name: /dev/dvdrw
          logical name: /dev/sr0
          version: 1.00
          capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
          configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
```

Do my symptoms point to a driver issue? In which case how can I ensure that I have the right driver and change it if necessary.

Has anyone had a similar problem ?

Can anyone tell me where I can find out more about the reported I/O errors?

Comment: If it does not have a tray then you obviously can not tell it to close the tray.

Comment: I was not aware that there wa

Comment: Sorry - not quick enough:    I was not aware that there was an "open tray" command.  I used "eject" hoping that it would do just that.

Comment: `eject -t` means close the tray.